# Many teal, or winter water

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

> What is the name of many teal or winter water, mating birds, or early travelers?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the poetry tag doesn't apply here. If I'm mistaken, feel free to revert my edit.

Comment: How doesn't the poetry tag apply?

Comment: Tag descriptions reads "Puzzles that are presented in the form of any of the various types of poetry." I'm not good at poetry but I don't see anything that looks like it here. How does it apply?

Comment: Poetry takes many forms, and water rhymes with traveler.

Comment: Two words that rhyme (approximately) don't make a poem, but I'm not going to argue on what poetry is or is not, this is not the point. The point is "does this question belong to the poetry category here". Take a look at it and see if your question is expected to be found there. If you know better, like I said, feel free to revert my edit.

Comment: I wouldn't argue on poetry either, because poetry doesn't have to rhyme, but " Literary work in which special intensity is given to the expression of feelings and ideas by the use of distinctive style or rhythm." And this "poem" captures the essence of spring indirectly, making use of style and rhythm. Because I made each variable have two syllables that convey the setting of spring. I will make a poem that will try to show what poetry can be.

Answer (score 3):

> Pretty sure you are Spring

Reason:

> Spring refers to a group of teal. The Spring season is when birds mate. (winter water) refers to water that melts from winter to spring and early travellers refer to when tourism occurs during the springtime.

Comment: How about now??

Comment: Yup. That is the answer. Tourism mostly happens in mid-July through September, so it would be pretty early to travel in the spring. And winter water means when snow melts in the spring it becomes winter water.

Comment: How about spring break? That's a fairly common time for families to travel.